# Configure Spring Boot @KafkaListener for listening to the latest messages

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Boot's @KafkaListener to monitor some server's heartbeat messages as:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "heartbeat-topic", groupId = "monitor")
public void listenToHeartbeatMsg(String message) {}
```

Issue is when the listener subscriber application started, even though the server is down, subscriber application will be receiving those previous heartbeat messages.

How can I fix this issue and listen only for real-time heartbeat messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `ConsumerSeekAware` and, in `onPartitionsAssigned` call seekToBeginning on the callback.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#seek

```java
public class MyListener implements ConsumerSeekAware {

...

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        callback.seekToEnd(assignments.keySet());
    }

}
```

Comment: If I read the question correctly, I think OP wants seek to the end

Comment: Yes it should be: callback.seekToEnd(assignments.keySet());

Comment: Sure; copy/paste issue :)